# How do I only call the dictionary value within a list if it meets a condition?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to call all the values from a dictionary that is within a list if the value of the key is within a separate list.

For example, I have this listed dictionary:

```
status = [{'name': 'Carrousel', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
 {'name': 'Balloon Flite', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
 {'name': 'Skyrush', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': False, 'single_rider': None},
 {'name': 'SooperDooperLooper',
  'wait': 5,
  'isOpen': True,
  'single_rider': None},
 {'name': 'Fahrenheit', 'wait': 20, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
 {'name': 'Dummy', 'wait': 0, 'isOpen': False, 'single_rider': None}]
```

I also have this list:

```
route = ['Skyrush', 'SooperDooperLooper', 'Carrousel', 'Fahrenheit']
```

Basically, I wanted to print out the values of `'wait'` in `status` for those names in `route`.

I know how to call the values of the row if I know the index but I'm having trouble trying to call only rows that contains the specific value of 'name'.

My expected result is something like:

```
0
5
0
20
```

Those are basically the 'wait' times of each respective rides in consecutive order within `route`.

Thank you! Any help would be greatly appreciated. I looked through other postings but couldn't find anything that is similar to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding too @Chris's answer, to get the expected order:

```
[d['wait'] for d in sorted(status, key=lambda x: ''.join(route).find(x['name'])) if d['name'] in route]
```

Output:

```
[0, 5, 0, 20]
```

Comment: Nice use of `sorted`! Think this serves the OP's desired output better. +1 :)

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the up-vote :-) yeah, order matters :-)

Comment: @peterpra Thanks, happy to help :-)

Answer (score 2):

Use list comprehension:

```
[d['wait'] for d in status if d['name'] in route]
```

Output:

```
[0, 0, 5, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in @Chris's answer, a list comprehension is the way to go.

However, if you want the order to be the order matching your `route`, this would be a solution:

```
[next(s for s in status if s['name'] == name)['wait'] for name in route]
```

That actually gets you `[0, 5, 0, 20]` instead of `[0, 0, 5, 20]`.

This also directly answers your actual question: how to access a list item in a list of dictionaries, by referencing a dictionary key.

```
next(item for item in some_list_of_dicts if s['key'] == 'some value')
```

Gets you the first item matching the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach: Change your input so you can access things more easily

```
name_indexed_status = dict(map(lambda x: (x.pop("name"), x), status))
print (str(name_indexed_status))
for r in route:
    print(name_indexed_status[r]["wait"])
```

> {
> 'Carrousel': {'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
> 'Balloon Flite': {'wait': 0, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
> 'Skyrush': {'wait': 0, 'isOpen': False, 'single_rider': None},
> 'SooperDooperLooper': {'wait': 5, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
> 'Fahrenheit': {'wait': 20, 'isOpen': True, 'single_rider': None},
> 'Dummy': {'wait': 0, 'isOpen': False, 'single_rider': None}
> }
>
> 0
> 5
> 0
> 20